# Keras: How to build a model with the form like a(x)u+b(x)

Tags: python, keras

I got stuck in trying to create a model in Keras representing a function a(x)u+b(x) where a(x) and b(x) are 2 nonlinear functions that I want to do regression and u is a changing variable.  Below is the code of doing regression for a(x)+b(x) using Keras concatenation if we don't have "u". But how we should insert this u into the structure so that it becomes a(x)u+b(x). Thanks.

def build_model():

```
A = Input(shape=[3])
B = Input(shape=[3])
a1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(A)
b1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(B)
c = concatenate([a1, b1])
O = Dense(1, activation='linear')(c)
model = Model(inputs=[A, B], outputs=O)
model.compile()

return model
```

Comment: How does `u` change? Can you please describe `u` a little more?

Comment: u is actually the control of my system. It is a scalar, but changing variable that we can get. You can think about we have a look up table that given any "x", we know a "u"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following. Note that there is a single input, and that input is connected to two separate dense layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tfk = tf.keras
tfkl = tfk.layers

def build_model(u):
    """Return model representing `a(x)u+b(x)`."""
    inputs = tfkl.Input(shape=[3])
    ax = tfkl.Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
    axu = tfkl.Lambda(lambda x: x * u)(ax)
    bx = tfkl.Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = tfkl.Concatenate()([axu, bx])
    x = tfkl.Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
    model = tfk.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
    return model
```

In your original code, you used a `Concatenate` layer. Are you sure you want that and not a elementwise sum?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just write a very original structure and that does not need to be concatenate layer. I will test this structure and mark your answer as correct if that works. (I don't know the routine of stackoverflow but I see other people do this.) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just one more question, this network seems to have "u" as an input of the function "build_model", which means that  once we call the function "build_model" with a "u", it is fixed in the network. What I want is that "u" is a changing variable, something like an input of the network like x. Suppose I make "x" and "u" both input of the network, then it will become a function of a(x,u). I just want to isolate this "u" to be a(x)u, would this be possible? Or they are actually equivalent? Thanks.